# Как использовать Windows SDK с компилятором MinGW32?

Tags: c, windows, codeblocks, sdk

Я использую компилятор **MinGW32** и IDE **Code::Blocks**, в связи с чем при использовании **WinAPI** у меня возникают проблемы - очень многие заголовки и определения функций отсутствуют в том комплекте, который поставляется вместе с компилятором.

Например:

```
#include <KnownFolders.h>// no such file
#include <VersionHelpers.h>// no such file
#include <strsafe.h>// no such file

SHGetKnownFolderPath(...);// undefined reference
StringCbLengthW(...);// undefined reference
```

Я скачал и установил **Windows SDK**. Проверил - требуемые мне вещи действительно установились в заданное расположение.

Но я никак не могу понять, как использовать эти ресурсы с моими инструментами разработки...

Попытался использовать установленный **Windows SDK**, прописав к нему пути в настройках проекта. Это не помогло - заголовков и папок слишком много, я не могу понять, что и где нужно искать, что использовать.

Это вообще возможно? Или **Windows SDK** предназначен только для использования с **MS Visual Studio**?

Что необходимо сделать, чтобы я мог использовать все средства **WinAPI** с компилятором **MinGW32**?

Comment: Собственно, нужных каталогов в Platform SDK всего два - include и lib. Вопрос только в том, понимает ли Mingw формат lib или хотя бы есть ли возможность конвертировать. К тому же VS подключает .lib из SDK автоматом, а ваш компилятор скорее всего так не умеет. Придется писать кучу `#pragma comment(lib, ...`.

Comment: Попробуйте mingw-w64. Заголовочник `knownfolders.h` присутствует (скорее всего и остальные будут - не проверял).

Comment: Похоже, так и придется использовать mingw-w64. Скажите, имеет ли этот компилятор возможность собирать для х32 и х64? И не возникнет ли проблем с библиотеками, которые работают с mingw32? Например, SDL.